# how to get the key and value in the object in list of array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, key-value

How to get the distinct keys ($key) and multiple different values ($myObjectValues) in list of objects?

My expected outcome is distinct keys displays as column in table and its different values display as multiple rows. The column ($key) should not be hardcore and I plan to display in blade view.

Ideal:
[image]

Current Code:

```
foreach($x as $key => $item) {

    print_r($key); //this is list number

    foreach($item as $key => $myObjectValues){

        print_r($key); //this is my object key
        print_r($myObjectValues); //this is my object values
    }
}
```

This is the json array object ($x).

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [milk_temperature] => 10
        [coffeebean_level] => 124.022
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [milk_temperature] => 1099
        [soya_temperature] => 10
        [coffeebean_level] => 99.022
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [milk_temperature] => 1099
        [coffeebean_level] => 99.022
    )
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, can you give an example of the ideal outcome?

Comment: are you saying that foreach of the keys you would like to make ANOTHER object with the rest of the values that have the same key? i am not sure i understood right

Comment: hi all, i edited the question.

Comment: ah now i get it, all you have to do here is to make a `foreach` loop trough your object that holds all your information(the ones you want into a table) and print each row on a table row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this, it's not the best approach in the world but it works and you can use it as an example. First you create a list with the table header titles and then start by printing the header and then the values.

```
<?php

$x = [
    (object) [
        'milk_temperature' => 10,
        'coffeebean_level' => 124.022
    ],
    (object) [
        'milk_temperature' => 1099,
        'soya_temperature' => 10,
        'coffeebean_level' => 99.022
    ],
    (object) [
        'milk_temperature' => 1099,
        'coffeebean_level' => 99.022
    ]
];

// list all the keys
$keys = [];
foreach($x as $key => $item) {
    $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys((array) $item));
}

$keys = array_unique($keys);

// echo the header
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $key . ' ';
}
echo "\n";

// echo the values
foreach($x as $item) {
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        echo $item->$key ?? '-'; // PHP 7+ solution
        // echo isset($item->$key) ? $item->$key : '-'; // PHP 5.6+
        echo ' ';
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the keys of the array with `array_keys()` and `array_collapse()`:

```
$columns = array_keys(array_collapse($records));
```

Then you look through the $records using the same loop you already have. Let's demo it with this example:

```
    $columns = array_keys(array_collapse($records));

    foreach($records as $key => $item) {

        //these are each record
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            //each column where you build the header

            // converts $item to an array
            $item = (array)$item;

            if (! array_key_exists($column, (array)$item)) {
                // show '---'
                echo '---';
                continue;
            }
            //show $item[$item]
            echo $item[$column];
        }
    }
```

The great advantage of doing so i.e getting the columns first (apart from converting the stdClass to an array) is that the columns array can be used any way you deem fit.

> It would be more beneficial if you can have your data all as array then you can easily use the array functions available on it.